# Default value of KeyboardEvent with useState

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm listening to `keydown` in `document` from a React component:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

function App() {
  const [keyEvent, setKeyEvent] = useState<KeyboardEvent>()

  function handleDocumentKeyDown(event: any) {
        setKeyEvent(event)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        // Can't use React onKeyDown in input because the event won't trigger outside of the input
        document.addEventListener('keydown', handleDocumentKeyDown)

        return () => {
            document.removeEventListener('keydown', handleDocumentKeyDown)
        }
    }, [])

  return (
    <div>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root")
render(<App />, rootElement)
```

I don't know what default value to give to `keyEvent`.

`useState<KeyboardEvent>({})` throws this TypeScript error:

> Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'KeyboardEvent | (() => KeyboardEvent)'.

`useState<KeyboardEvent>(null)` throws this TypeScript error:

> Argument of type 'null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'KeyboardEvent | (() => KeyboardEvent)'.ts(2345)

Comment: May be `useState<KeyboardEvent>({} as KeyboardEvent)` hack could work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
const [keyEvent, setKeyEvent] = useState<KeyboardEvent | null>(null);
```

It should work, and I think it's quite explicit and clear.
Then, if you'll need to set it back to null somewhere in the future, you'd also won't face any type errors.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you can use `React.KeyboardEvent<Element>`, but for document handlers `React.KeyboardEvent<Document>` should works